# Оффлайн карты для Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, map

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли sdk, позволяющие выкачивать карты определенной местности с зумом до ~23.

Пробовал mapbox столкнулся с проблемой в ограничении кэша, на выкачанные тайлы. То есть больше 50 мб не скачать.
Вот [здесь](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/4411) и [здесь](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/eb1b385e50f783e33bb500693977f7bf45f4126e/include/mbgl/util/constants.hpp#L39) описана эта проблема.

Может быть есть какая то возможность выкачивать тайлы и сохранять их локально , а потом скармливать их провайдеру?
Может есть sdk которые дают выкачивать, пусть даже платные,но за приемлимую цену?

За любую полезную информацию , был бы очень благодарен.